# Java SwingWorker isInterrputed returns false after cancel

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have a piece of code that downloads a file. This happens in a SwingWorker doInBackground method. (See code below) file is a File object (temp dir) the connection is an URLConnection object that holds the url from the file to be downloaded. (url.openConnection())
The download works properly in the SwingWorker, apart from the canceling...

```
SwingWorker<Integer,Integer> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<Integer,Integer>() {

    int contentLength = 0;
    int bytesDownloaded = 0;

    double speed = 0;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

    setStatus("Dowloading...");

    URL url = null;
    URLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(MainScreen.getUrl()); // Gets a URL entered earlier to dowload
        connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(doelBestand));

        contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        final double nanosPerSecond = 1000000000.0;
        final double bytesPerMB = 1024 * 1024;

        while(true) {
        int b = inputStream.read();
        bytesDownloaded += b;
        speed = nanosPerSecond / bytesPerMB * bytesDownloaded / (System.nanoTime() - start + 1);
        process();
        if (b == -1 || Thread.interrupted()) {
            break;
        }
        outputStream.write(b);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        try {
        if(outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        } catch (IOException ex) { }
        try {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.getInputStream().close();
        }
        } catch (IOException ex) {  }
    }
    return 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setValue(100);
    lblPercent.setText("100 %");
    btnStartCancel.setEnabled(false);
    btnOpenFolder.setEnabled(true);
    chkCloseOnFinish.setEnabled(false);
    state = State.DONE;
    }

    protected void process() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); 
    if(speed > 0) {
        lblDownloadSpeed.setText(df.format(speed) + " mb/s");
    }

    if(contentLength > 0) {
        Integer percent = (int) (bytesDownloaded / (contentLength / 100.0));
        progressBar.setValue(percent);
        lblPercent.setText(percent + " %");
    } else {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    }
};
```

But when the user presses the Start/Cancel button when the state of the program is 'downloading' I'm calling the `swingWorker.cancel(true);` method.

```
switch(state) {
    case READY:
    state = State.DOWNLOADING;
    btnStartCancel.setText("Cancel");

    swingWorker.execute();
    break;
    case DOWNLOADING:
    swingWorker.cancel(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    lblPercent.setText("Download was cancelled by the user.");
    btnStartCancel.setText("Start");
    btnStartCancel.setEnabled(true);
    break;
    case DONE:
    // Do nothing
    break;

}
```

But the `isInterrupted()` does always return false, and so it continues running the thread, however the cancel function does return true.

I have also tried `while(!isCancelled())`, but that does also keep on returning false.

There's also a problem that when it's cancelled, it NEVER stops, so it becomes an infinite thread. (int b keeps on running being added and bytesDownloaded will grow and grow). It's not infinite as long as the download is completed without the cancel (then b will be -1) and the loop will break.

How can I make sure the swingWorker will abort the download?

Comment: I guess that the blocking method is the read() from the InputStream class, or perpahps some other method is blocking a one. So, despedites, that you program a well structured method, but one of the operations is blocking the excution flow. So besides of inturrumping the thread (that is necesary to terminate it) you must ,also, interrumpt the blocking operation (that i guess is the read of the inputstream)

Comment: First of all, make sure that the `SwingWorker` instance you are invoking `cancel` on is really the same that you have used to launch the background task. Since you are *not* creating your `SwingWorker` within the `switch` statement you have shown to us, it’s very likely that you are creating it (and overwriting the reference variable) at the wrong place. Further, your implementation is fundamentally broken as you are accessing and even manipulating the GUI from the background thread.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. @Holger The switch statement comes right after the swingworker. Both are in the same function as well. As you can see it gets executed successfully at the READY state  `swingWorker.execute()` There are no other threads, which mean that we can rule out that it might get overwritten.

What is a more proper way to update the GUI from the worker?

Comment: You are creating the swingworker *before* the `switch` statement, i.e. you are creating it even if `state` is `DOWNLOADING` already? Think about it. The proper way of updating is [documented in the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). You may use `PropertyChangeListener` notification or `publish`/`process` queuing.

Comment: Why you don't try to use custom flags? Say.. a boolean value (instead of using the signal underlying system of the SwingWorker). I suspect that the cancel method only set's an internal boolean value, that is the same that is returned on the isCanceled().